# Google Earth Engine - Calculate 90th percentile with sliding window of days

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm looking to calculate the 90th percentile over an image collection of 10 years. Since, only 10 numbers is small I want to add a sliding window of 5 days on either side of percentile calculation. For example, for 01/05 I want to use 01/01-01/10 of all 10 year range (1981-1990) to calculate the 90th percentile for that day. This is the code I have so far:

```
//Load PRISM tmax imagery
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('OREGONSTATE/PRISM/AN81d')
              .select('tmax');

// Define reference conditions from the first 10 years of data.
var reference = dataset.filterDate('1981-01-01', '1990-12-31')
// Sort chronologically in descending order.
  .sort('system:time_start', false);

// Compute the 90th percentile of historical 10 years
var historical_p90 = reference.reduce(ee.Reducer.percentile([90]));
print(historical_p90)
```

Comment: Basically I'm looking to calculate the 90th percentile for each day of year over a 10 year time frame incorporating 5 days before and after to increase amount of date for percentile calculation